# NPM package's dependency requires lower version than the "wanted" version

Tags: javascript, npm

For example, I have `"typescript": "^2.8.3"` but `"@angular/compiler-cli": "6.0.2"` requires Typescript >=2.7.2 and <2.8.0. How would I update my package.json to always want the highest version of a dependency allowed by dependent packages?

I've already set the dependency in package.json manually using the "~" prefix, but that will keep it locked in and not upgrade to higher major or minor versions when the package depends on a higher version.

Comment: Looking at the github repository, it appears that their [accepted range has been updated to `<2.9`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/compiler-cli/package.json#L18), but [their latest published version on npm](https://unpkg.com/@angular/compiler-cli@6.0.2/package.json) appears to not include this update. Perhaps submit an issue on the repository asking for another snapshot to be published to npm including this range of versions.

Comment: but why do you ever need to specify 2nd level  dependency's version explicitly?

Comment: In the meanwhile, I believe you may be able to point `@angular/compiler-cli` directly to the github repository by using `"@angular/compiler-cli": "angular/angular/packages/compiler-cli"` while you wait for your request to be fulfilled. I know that syntax works for top-level repositories, but I've never tested for a subdirectory of a repository like this before.

Comment: @skyboyer it's under `peerDependencies`, not `dependencies`.

Comment: Thanks for looking into that, but does that make sense about the problem I'm having? When you install a package, everything it needs is installed and updated automatically so I never worried about it but now that I got a dependency out of line I guess, from here on out it's up to me to manage that dependency manually. Is there no way to fix it? The problem is on my end, not the package author.